# Output of one query as an input to another query in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Lets say i have 4 tables.(name, place, sex, status)

I will be having a Roll number initially.
Now i go to "name" table to get the Name for the Corresponding roll number.
Now i come to "place" table, n with the help of NAME, i will try to find out place.
Then i go to "sex" table, n  with the help of PLACE, i will try to find out sex.
Then i go to "status" table, n with the help of SEX, i will try to find the status.

Can any one please help me, so that as soon as i give the roll number it should give me the status for that roll number.

Advance Thanks,
Harisha.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select *
from name join place on name.name=place.name) as t1

(select *

from t1 join sex on t1.place=sex.place) as t2

(select *

from t2 join status on t2.sex=status.sex) as t3
```

Now write the code on t3 to get the status for any given roll number

```
select status 

from t3

where rollnumber="A1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query multiple tables in a single query. It will be something like:

```
SELECT
    s.SomeColumn
FROM
    Name as n
       INNER JOIN
    Place as p
       ON
           n.NameColumnA = p.PlaceColumnA
       INNER JOIN
    Sex sex
       ON
           p.PlaceColumnB = sex.SexColumnC
       INNER JOIN
    Status s
       ON
           sex.SexColumnD = s.StatusColumnF
WHERE
    n.RollNumber = 5;
```

Unfortunately, you've not given nearly enough information for me to know which columns are to be used for each join.